# What's the shortest way to apply different function on each array element?

Tags: ruby

Say I have many arrays of same size, with some elements, for example one of those could be:

`arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

I want to call a **different** function on each element, depending on its index, so I could do this:

```
arr.each_with_index do do |el, idx| 
  case idx
  when 0
    functionA el
  when 1
    functionB el
  # and so on..
  end
end
```

Is there any shorter way to do this? Something similar to assigning to variables:

```
a, b, c, d = arr
```

but I want to call functions, instead of doing assignment.

Comment: I don't see you passing element to `functionA`. So it's not really "applying".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could prepare an array of funcs and then zip the two together. Something like this:

```
# stabby lambdas instead of methods. Because methods aren't objects.
func_a = ->(el) { puts "1 for #{el}" }
func_b = ->(el) { puts "2 for #{el}" }
func_c = ->(el) { puts "3 for #{el}" }


arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
funcs = [func_a, func_b, func_c, func_a] # reusing func_a

arr.zip(funcs) {|a, f| f.call(a) }

# >> 1 for a
# >> 2 for b
# >> 3 for c
# >> 1 for d
```

### But my methods are methods, not lambdas...

Here's a trick how to turn methods to proc objects, so that you can put them in array and call later. Be wary, though, that those calls are more expensive as compared to regular methods (shouldn't matter, unless you're already squeezing cycles out of your CPU)

```
def func_a el; puts "1 for #{el}"; end
def func_b el; puts "2 for #{el}"; end
def func_c el; puts "3 for #{el}"; end


arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
funcs = [method(:func_a), method(:func_b), method(:func_c), method(:func_a)] # reusing func_a

arr.zip(funcs) {|a, f| f.call(a) }

# >> 1 for a
# >> 2 for b
# >> 3 for c
# >> 1 for d
```

Comment: nice, I wasn't even aware of 'zip'

Comment: @JamesAdam: I find new things most every day :)

Comment: BTW: if you flip those two arrays around, you can use `Symbol#to_proc`: `funcs.zip(arr, &:call)`. And if you have an array of method *names* instead of `Proc`s, you can do `funcs.zip(arr, &:send)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I've tried both your suggestions, neither worked (MRI 1.9.3). Could you paste them somewhere online?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks, I used the methods way and it works fine. Suppose it's faster to get the `Method` objects right into the array as you did it, instead of using symbols to do send(f, a) as @AndyH suggested? It seems cleaner with symbols.

Comment: I feel that symbols and `send` should be faster.

Comment: Ah, I forgot: destructuring bind doesn't work with `Symbol#to_proc`. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Sergio's answer, if the functions you want to call *are* methods, you could do something like this:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
funcs = [:method_a, :method_b, :method_c, :method_d]

arr.zip(funcs) {|a, f| send(f, a) }

# or if they are methods on some other object
arr.zip(funcs) {|a, f| that_other_object.send(f, a) }
```